# C# Combobox not populating from list correctly

Tags: c#, list, combobox, formatting, settings

I have a combo box that I am attempting to populate from "Settings" AFTER the data has been edited by a user. I am running into 1 of two weird issues.

Issue 1.) If I write the code like this:

`var list = Properties.UserSpecific.Default.webCombo.Cast<string>().ToList(); 
comboBox7.Items.Add(list);`

I end up getting this:

[image]

So I tried writing it like this:

```
        string[] webDropDown = Properties.UserSpecific.Default.webCombo.Cast<string>().ToArray();
        comboBox7.DataSource = webDropDown;
```

But it is giving me my data all on 1 line.

[image]

As far as I can tell the data isn't on 1 line. I can write to a richtextbox and it shows up on individual lines. So I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have other lines of code:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = Globals.combo1;
```

Where I don't have this issue at all. Best I can tell the issue is happening because I am attempting to allow for a User to be able to Customize a `Systems.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection` in my settings page. I am accomplishing this by using this code to update:

```
            List<string> display = new List<string>();
        display.Add(richTextBox1.Text);
        Properties.UserSpecific.Default.webCombo.Clear();
        foreach(string str in display)
        {
            Properties.UserSpecific.Default.webCombo.Add(str);
        }
        //Save All Changes
        Properties.UserSpecific.Default.Save();
```

I am displaying this back using:

```
            //Populate DropDown Box For Websites
        var list = Properties.UserSpecific.Default.webCombo.Cast<string>().ToList();
        foreach (string str in list)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += str;
        }
```

Clearly I am doing something wrong, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

```
string[] webDropDown = Properties.UserSpecific.Default.webCombo.Cast<string>().ToArray();
comboBox7.Items.AddRange(webDropDown);
```

Comment: Thank you Ken this helped I also had to make some changes as pointed out by Ajith Nair below.

Answer (score 1):

The following lines of code is creating the issue.

```
List<string> display = new List<string>();
display.Add(richTextBox1.Text);
```

It will add the entire text as a single item.

Try something like below.

```
 List<string> display = new List<string>();
 display = richTextBox1.Text.Split('\n').ToList<string>();
```

Comment: Thank you Ajith Nair this along with Ken's comment up above got be fixed up.

Answer (score 0):

Add is for items themselves

Try

```
foreach(string item in list)
{
    comboBox7.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted the solution on behalf of the question author to move it to the answer space).*

Ken and Ajith below got me pointed in the right direction. I ended up following Ken's advice and using:

```
           string[] webDropDown = Properties.UserSpecific.Default.webCombo.Cast<string>().ToArray();
        comboBox7.Items.AddRange(webDropDown);
```

I also had to follow Ajith's advice and make changes:

```
display = richTextBox1.Text.Split('\n').ToList<string>();
```

As well as a change to the way I was displaying the content back to my Editor:

```
        var list = Properties.UserSpecific.Default.webCombo.Cast<string>().ToList();
        foreach (string str in list)
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += str + Environment.NewLine;
        }
```